# how do i input the previous Genuine product key in to the bios

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bios

I have an HP desktop computer (HP Prodesk 600G1). A lightning strike fried the main board, so I bought a replacement. How do I input the previous Genuine product key into the bios?

Comment: Not sure this is *technically* legal, regardless of whether it's at all possible - the license was assigned to the HP system from the OEM. With the new motherboard, you are effectively no longer on the system for which the license was assigned. I haven't had to deal with system recovery using this sort of Windows license yet though. Normally, I'd expect a sticker with a Product Key to be placed somewhere on or inside the system chassis - is there not one for yours?

Comment: Alternately: Have you wiped the HDD yet? If not, recovery tools like [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) may still be usable.

Comment: i have not wiped the HDD, its says windows is not Genuine,

Comment: So, you just replaced the motherboard and rebooted without rebuilding the OS? Is it prompting you for a Product Key, or just asking you to activate? If prompting for a Product Key, try pulling the key with ProduKey and using that. If asking for activation, try following the process for activation via telephone.

Comment: i have replaced the same Mainboard, i am looking for the bios update that enables the hidden settings,

Comment: As @magicandre1981 has stated, there is not likely to be any tool available to the end-user which will allow you to set or recover the license information from the UEFI. The only way for end-users to provide license details is through entering a Product Key (e.g.: Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` and click "Change product key"). Please see my earlier comments for resources which can assist with recovering the key needed for this, or following up with additional activation steps. Let us know if those work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a Product key into the BIOS/UEFI. This can be only done by OEMs with special tools from Microsoft.

Comment: it might be available in HP service centers?

Comment: no. Ask HP for support why the key is not embedded any longer.